# how to use loops to compare sequences?

Tags: python

I am trying to compare the two sequences, a and b, and write code that prints out where these mismatches are.  I know the code below is not correct, but it is the closest I can come for the sake of this.  I feel I am misunderstanding something about the concept of flow.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
a="CATCGTCCT"
b="CACCGACCG"
mismatch_seq=[]
for x in list(a):
    mismatch=[]
    if x!=x in list(b):
        mismatch+=x in list(b)
        mismatch_seq.append(mismatch)
    else:
       pass
print mismatch_seq
```

EDIT: In addition, how would you write code to tell you where, in terms of index, this mismatch occurred?

Comment: You don't need to use the `list()` construct. Strings can be iterated over in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
a="CATCGTCCT"
b="CACCGACCG"
mismatch_seq=[]
for x in range (0, len(a)):
    if a[x] !=  b[x]:
        mismatch_seq.append(x)
print mismatch_seq
```

Comment: Ah ok, thank you.  How would you go about asking the code to tell you the index of the mismatch element as well?

Comment: Just replace `mismatch_seq.append(x)` with `mismatch_seq.append(a[x])` or `mismatch_seq.append(b[x])`

Comment: I'm still only getting the element, not the index of the element when I do that.

Comment: When you say index, you mean like the position in the string, right? `mismatch_eq.append(x)` should get you the index (position in the string) of the mismatched characters. Be careful that it starts counting from 0, not 1. For example, when I run this example, you should get [2,5,8], which are the index of the mismatched characters.

Comment: If you want the code to show both the index and the elements, just create a new list, say `mismatch_idx` and just under `mismatch_seq.append(x)`, put `mismatch_idx.append(a[x]` or `mismatch_idx.append(b[x])`.

Comment: Ok no I see it now.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the preceding answers, this [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) looks at characters in `b` where corresponding characters in `a` exist, and returns their index `i` if those positions are not equal.

```
a = "CATCGTCCT"
b = "CACCGACCG"

mismatch = [i for i in range(0, len(a)) if a[i] != b[i]]

for pos in mismatch:
    print "At position", pos, "a had", a[pos], "while b had", b[pos], "."
```

Equivalent loop code for `mismatch` would be, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26269731/1091386):

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i] != b[i]:
        mismatch.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the following:

```
>>> filter(lambda m: m[1][0] != m[1][1] , enumerate(zip(a, b)))
[(2, ('T', 'C')), (5, ('T', 'A')), (8, ('T', 'G'))]
```

I would recommend using `izip`. This way you can put in entire files which are arbitrarily long, and then can safely send the output to a file ...

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic code may use this

```
a = "CATCGTCCT"                                             # SET a
b = "CACCGACCG"                                             # SET b

aListOfMismatchPOSITIONs = []                               # SET aList

for charPTR in range( len( a ) ):                           # LOOP over len( a )
    if  a[charPTR] != b[charPTR]:                           # .NE.
        aListOfMismatchPOSITIONs.append( charPTR)           #     APPEND
    else:                                                   # ELSE
        continue                                            #     LOOP^

print "A sequence of non-matching positions = ", aListOfMismatchPOSITIONs
```